# 2014 Kawasaki Ninja EX300A Clutch

Tags: motorcycle, clutch, kawasaki

So I'm getting to the point of having to replace my clutch components (planning on just the standard "kit" parts, friction & clutch plates and new springs), and I haven't been able to find what the actual spec is. I haven't ever done any clutch work before (aside from cable adjustment) so I don't really know how to match the specs.

So the question: Can someone tell me what the OE spec is for a clutch kit, and how to I match that to an aftermarket clutch kit?

I was looking at [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CAYACQ6), which has the numbers "303-45-10032," but since I don't understand the clutch spec'ing at all, that's kind of useless to me at the moment. :)

Anyway, thanks in advance everyone.

---

### Added for clarity

What I'm really trying to figure out is what specs do I need to look at to be sure a product is a proper match... like friction pad thickness? Tooth count/angle? Things like this. Do these specs even exist? Or are clutch kits simply "this clutch kit fits this vehicle" and that's all? No specs involved...?

Comment: What exact spec are you looking to figure out? Spec on *what aspect* of the clutch?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Basically, I need to understand how to order the correct replacement parts. Personally I find that buying (online in particular) anything can be open to mismatch, and that by understanding the parts and how they're marked/named I can be sure I'm buying the right thing. As an example, if you know the style, width and link count, you can get any aftermarket chain and know what's a proper ft and what's not. Same with tires. That's basically what I'm trying to discover: what is the spec for clutch/friction plates that I need to know for replacement?

Comment: 303-45-10032 is the Barnett part number which is listed as the kit for your bike on Barnett's web site http://www.barnettclutches.com/1920/kawasaki/0/0/2014-kawasaki-ninja-300.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kit will consist of Metal Rings, Friction Rings and Clutch Springs.

The Metal Rings will have a minimum thickness.
The Friction Rings will have a minimum thickness.
The Clutch Springs will have a minimum unloaded length.
The stack (all the Metal and Friction rings) will have a minimum thickness.

Since motorcycle clutches are multi-plate there are lots of options, I myself have added a metal ring or friction ring to a worn clutch to bring the stack thickness back into spec. I have also added washers to worn clutch springs to bring them back to life and stop the clutch from slipping.

Buy a clutch kit. Take your old clutch parts out and hold the old and new components together to confirm they are compatible by eye.

Be careful when installing the stack that you have all the components in the right order. One of the metal rings may be different to the others and is for the bottom or top of the stack, you must use the old clutch as a guide for the correct assembly of the new clutch.

Also you should soak all the friction plates in engine oil before assembling the stack so as not to burn the clutch when it is first installed.

I have looked at the kit you linked and it is the correct kit for your bike.

One more tip, if you lean the bike on its side with the clutch side up then you will not need to drain the oil before removing the clutch cover.

Comment: Thanks r.anderson. Your answer definitely provides some good info on the flexibility of motorcycle clutch maintenance. If I don't get a better answer by tomorrow I'll mark it as the answer.